# WildFly common.sh script is missing

Tags: wildfly

When I try to run WildFly version 13.x with standalone.sh script I get this message:

```
./standalone.sh: 43: .: Can't open ./common.sh
```

I checked and indeed the file common.sh is missing from the WildFly bin directory, however in version 14.0.1 common.sh exists.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In WildFly 13, `standalone.sh` doesn't have any reference to common.sh at line 43. It is placed at `standalone.sh` of WildFly 14...

Check a fresh install because seems you are mixing scripts.